# Why does QGIS add decimals when a csv is saved as a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

When I save a csv as shapefile the fields with decimals are saved adding decimals, then the new table in some case has new values.

Old Table (CSV)

```
ALTURA ELI  ALTURA ORT
1.94        39.6
-11.19      28.22
-36.88      2.59
-33.64      6.08
```

New Table (DBF/SHP)

```
ALTURA ELI  ALTURA ORT
1.940000000000000,39.600000000000001,
-11.190000000000000,28.219999999999999,
-36.880000000000003,2.590000000000000,
-33.640000000000001,6.080000000000000,
```

Comment: how did you save the file? Tried the mmqgis plugin?

Comment: Hi, Curlew. I use "Add delimited text layer" then I save the layer as .shp using "Save as..."

Comment: Curlew, I have used mmggis and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I realize about that issue because when I tried to publish this layer as WFS using geoserver nothing is showed (no objects neither values in the table) just the field names in the table.

Comment: I noticed that all fields are created as String when I use mmqgis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you were able to use a plugin to get the values you wanted, but here's why the values were changing in the first place.

This isn't specific to QGIS or any other software, it's an issue with how the data is being stored. Floating point values are stored with a specific precision (number of digits). Some software will automatically round the stored values when displaying them but it's all stored the same.

For example, I can reproduce your values in Python:

The value prints out normally within the precision of the float type:

```
In [35]: '{0:2.14f}'.format(28.22)
Out[35]: '28.22000000000000'
```

but not if you try to print more precision than is stored:

```
In [36]: '{0:2.15f}'.format(28.22)
Out[36]: '28.219999999999999'
```

In some cases you may be able to store your values as strings (which may be what that plugin is doing), but that also has issues and won't work in all cases.

Comment: Thank you Evil Genius, I have noticed what you say in ypur last paragraph in my own data. So, this is not the solution I am looking for.